# StripLines with same properties displaying different width

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bar-chart, reportbuilder3.0

I have two different horizontal stripLines in my bar graph.  I am displaying a label for these stripLines through the use of a line chart data type with the corresponding values.  My problem is I have the same properties (other than actual value) for these stripLines, but they are displaying at 2 different widths.  Does the stripInterval have anything to do with this?

[image]

The interval and interval offset for the top line (1200/yr) is;

```
=Fields!BasicNeed.Value + Fields!LifeStyleNeed.Value
=Fields!BasicNeed.Value + Fields!LifeStyleNeed.Value + 1    (not sure what offset should really be but this displays great)
```

and for the bottom line which is appearing too thin;

```
=Fields!BasicNeed.Value
=Fields!BasicNeed.Value + 1
```

The BorderWidth, BorderStyle, BorderColor, StripWidth, IntervalTypes and everything else are all the exact same except for the actual values above.

Comment: The bars look the same width to me. It might be an optical illusion. Perhaps you could take a screenshot, load into paint and see how many pixels wide they are.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue.

The problem for me was that I was using the **StripWidth** property to control the width of the strip (what was I thinking?). That should be set to **0** - it's actually a proportion based on the total axis value.

Use the **BorderWidth** property to control the width of the Strip Line.

[image]

[image]

Also, make sure you set the **BorderStyle** to **Solid**. **Default** looks like **Solid** but is actually **None**.

Source: [Mark from Dundas](http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=19450)

Answer (score 0):

I would set the Interval property back to Auto.  You only need to set the IntervalOffset property.